# How to make sure that the signal was received before continuing

Tags: c, signals, fork

I have a few children process, I need to send a signal to the parent and make sure the signal was received before continuing

```
#define CHILD 0
int n = 0;

void handler(int sig)  {
    n--;
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int p ;
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler);

    if(argc == 2) {
        int k = atoi(argv[1]);
        n = k;
        while(k-- != 0) {
            p = fork();
            if(p == CHILD) {
                srand(time(NULL)); 
                int r = 1 +(rand()%10);
                printf("No:%d %d Child PID: %d times.%d\n",k,n, getpid(),r);

//                int rai = raise(SIGCHLD);
                printf("rai: %d  %d\n", rai, n);
                sleep(r);

                exit(1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        puts("Please provide k num of zombie to be generated\n");
    }

    while(p > CHILD && n > 0) {
        printf("sleeping 2  %d\n", n);
        sleep(2);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How can I be sure that the parent catch all the SIGCHILD signals
Imports were omitted on purpose

Comment: The POSIX `raise()` sends a signal to the calling thread/process, not to the parent.   If you want to send to the parent, you'll need to use another function (like `kill()`) that allows specifying the target process.   Once you have that sorted out, you'll need to implement some form of acknowledgement (e.g. on receiving a signal, the parent sends one back to the child) or some means that guarantees receipt.

Comment: Please note that `SIGCHLD` will automatically generated when the child process ended, so you need to raise another signal say `x` in your child processes, then you can set a signal handler in those child processes for signal say `y` and wait in those processes using `pause()`, then in your parent handler once it receives `x` make it raise `y` signal.

Comment: Do you really need to use signals, or are other ways of inter process communication also an option?